# Qt: Convert scoped enum to string using a template function

Tags: c++, qt

For logging purpose I want to convert my enums to human readable strings. Most of the time I'm using scoped enums, therefore I need a solution that also works for scoped enums.
Qt provides the Q_ENUM macro to safe me a lot of work. For converting a enum to string I can write this:

```
QMetaEnum::fromType<Class::Enum>().valueToKey(int(enum))
```

The explicit cast to int is necessary to convert the scoped enum to int, as `valueToKey` must be called using an integral value. This works for scoped enums but I would like to use some sort of template function for converting. I found the following template solution in a different question:

```
template<typename QEnum>
QString enumToString (QEnum value)
{
  return QMetaEnum::fromType<QEnum>().valueToKey(int(value));
}
```

But this does not work for scoped enums. Is there any template solution that also works for plain AND scoped enums?

**EXAMPLE:**

```
class LoggingManager : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    enum class Level
    {
        debug,
        info,
        warning,
        error,
        fatal
    };
    Q_ENUM(LoggingManager::Level)

enum Category
        {
            network,
            usb
        };
        Q_ENUM(Category)
    ...
}

QString level = enumToString(LoggingManager::Level::debug) // ""
QString level2 = QMetaEnum::fromType<LoggingManager::Level>().valueToKey(int(LoggingManager::Level::debug)) // "debug"
QString category = enumToString(LoggingManager::usb) // "usb"
```

Comment: Could you show an example that works/does not work?

Comment: I tried to replicate the behavior and for me the output of `qDebug() << level << level2 << category;` is `"" "" "usb"`. Are you sure it stops working in the template wrapper?

Comment: I'm stupid. The problem is Q_ENUM(LoggingManager::Level) if I write only Q_ENUM(Level) it works. Thank you, you made me rethink the problem. You can post this as an answer if you like.

Comment: Nice! I suggest you just write an answer yourself or close the question. Answering your own questions is encouraged on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, i figured it out.

The solution is to not use the scoped enum in the `Q_ENUM` macro.

**Wrong:**

```
Q_ENUM(Class::Enum)
```

**Correct:**

```
Q_ENUM(Enum)
```

For most use cases using the scoped or the non-scoped form is equivalent (When you are inside the class). I normally always use the scoped form even inside the class just be clear about what I want to say. But it seems that using the scoped enum directly in the macro breaks the functionality of the macro.

Perhaps somebody with a deeper knowledge of Qt can explain why this is the case. But I just remember that using the scoped form in the macro makes it broken.